# Cannot add PPA. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct

Tags: ppa

Internet connection is working.

apt-get is working.

Trying to add `ppa:cooperjona/lightread` but an error has raised:

```
Cannot add PPA 'ppa:cooperjona/lightread' . Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I supposed there is an error in writing or in the PPA.

I tried also the 'ppa:tombeckmann/ppa' but with same error.

Comment: The issue comes from your system, not the PPA, which works fine for me.

Comment: I tried all of this here and still got the same error.

Comment: If anyone of you ends up here and is using a proxy, check [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452595/cannot-add-ppa-behind-proxy-ubuntu-14-04) instead

Comment: @Anwar: I don't understand how the two are related. The accepted answer here is about certificates and not web proxy servers.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The linked answer has addressed both the issue and I feel that it's same problem with different answers.

Comment: @Anwar: I don't see anything about certificates in the answers to the linked question. I'm not comfortable to redirect readers to a question thread that omits a line of solution and is itself a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Ok, I'm voting to reopen it. But I still think this is same problem with different solutions. I'll discuss it later

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I googled the error and find [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/fix-cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that.html). So i tried to clone a git as he did there and has the same result.

So to solve this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

and things become smooth again :)

Comment: I tried this, but the same error exist and it does not work, ain't it odd?

Answer (score 40):

**Open Terminal and run the command:**

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`

**It may work, but if doesn't then run:**

`sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa`

**Instead of:**

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa`

Comment: note to reader: `sudo -E` preserves the user environment, including any proxy config.

Comment: Or if you're on a https restricted network and have to install another root certificate to trust the networks MITM policy, here's something that will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/645818/how-to-install-certificates-for-command-line

Comment: Still gives out `Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support jammy''.
`, same as before, when running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3`. It is put in a new [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420531/cannot-add-ppa-this-ppa-does-not-support-jammy-when-installing-sublime-t/1420532#1420532), goes too far here.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact error message about checking the PPA name or format. My network was connected and I could ping websites and browse fine.

What I finally figured out was the clock on my computer was set wrong. If it's off more than a small amount, the secure connection will fail and it will report this message. It's very unhelpful.

Check your clock. I set mine and then it immediately worked as expected.

Comment: Another issue causing this issue is a firewall (like Shorewall) blocking access to the internet. I had the exact same message - there was no other indication that the firewall was blocking.Though it worked after opening a port.