# I want to install deepin music player in my ubuntu?

Tags: ppa

I want to install deepin music player in my ubuntu. When I run

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:noobslab/deepin-sc
```

in terminal it says:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:noobslab/deepin-sc'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Why is this happening? And how do I install it?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? You need to find a newer version of deepin music player. We dropped ffmpeg a few releases ago and that one you are using is too old. By the way: Tim and me could add the repository myself with no problems and that should indicate your problem is NOT related to the PPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well how to install it is these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:noobslab/deepin-sc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install deepin-music-player
```

I ran them all and got no errors.

Something else is wrong. Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/deepin-sc
```

<sup>[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429803/cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that-the-ppa-name-or-format-is-correct)</sup>

If that doesn't work - do you have a proxy? If so - [solution is here](https://askubuntu.com/a/102505/186134).

Comment: No, I am. That explains why it works for you and not for me. I do not have ffmpeg but that newer thingy installed (probably avconv?)

Comment: One of the things installed was `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`

Comment: thank you Tim i didn't knew that proxy server would make that difference. Now it worked. And if i'm connected to another network without proxy do i need to make any change to sudo -E ??

Comment: @Bantawa I don't know about having to make changes to it... It should work without the -E if it is a proxy error?

Comment: i installed it succesfully, but i can't seem to launch it, i checked the dash in installed applications, i even tried to run it from the terminal but i'm getting an exception error in python?

Comment: is not available for 16.04 :(