# unable to play HEVC files on ubuntu 14.04 LTE

Tags: 14.04, vlc, media, hevc

I have tried VLC and totem players but they are not working.
I then searched and re-installed the VLC with latest version available, this time I am getting a green layer on the video.
Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install H.265 / HEVC codec on Ubuntu Linux?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/362745/how-to-install-h-265-hevc-codec-on-ubuntu-linux)

Answer (score 125):

VLC out of the box does not play HEVC files. To fix this we need to install `libde265` via PPA, which is an open source implementation of the h.265 video codec.

Open up the Terminal and run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

VLC should now play these media files.

Source: http://www.unixmen.com/fix-vlc-not-support-audio-video-format-hevc/

Comment: Only fix I could get to work for HEVC files in VLC. Cheers.

Comment: That worked for me.

Comment: In my system I could not add the repository ppa. Its telling me to check the PPA name and address. I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Please help.

Comment: Does this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/429803/cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that-the-ppa-name-or-format-is-correct

Comment: Doing this broke down vlc altogether for me (Error opening framebuffer device!).

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm without even restarting machine.

Comment: I cannot install from strukturag PPA (Xubuntu 16.04.3) - `E: Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

The above solution does not worked for me. But I found another solution and worked fine for me:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-libde265
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade VLC first, for which I used the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media/ .

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Don't forget to purge and remove these repos before upgrading to new Ubuntu version!**

Then I installed the `vlc-plugin`, see the other answer. And it started working.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Summed up at https://developer.jboss.org/people/ozizka/blog/2016/03/15/vlc-221-and-hevc-in-ubuntu-1404-lts .