# How to install certificates for command line

Tags: command-line, certificates, https

So in school we need to install a certificate to access https sites. In firefox, I can import the certificate. However, I can't do so with the command line. For example, running `git push` I get:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/repo': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

How do I import a certificate to remove this? The import must be able to authenticate for me. Also, it is a `.cer` file, so the answer for `.crt` will not work. Also, I do not want steps on how to setup git, as I already have. I want to know if it is possible to do that. Or can I just disable authentication with the `git` command totally and make it ignore certificates like what [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/648624/241602) here says? Also, I do not want the webpage to load, I have set firefox to do that. I want the `git push` command to give the standard output like:

```
[master 630d087] message
 1 file changed, 93 insertions(+), 80 deletions(-)
 rewrite somefile (84%)
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 978 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/User/Repo.git
   851ae39..630d087  master -> master
```

Note: I found out its `git config --global http.sslverify false`. But I would like to see an answer for everything, not just a git hack

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a root certificate?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate)

Comment: @EricCarvalho no, thats for `.crt`. I need `.cer`

Comment: Have you a problem with your git command or what you want to do? Give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: @A.B. I want to allow git to use the certificate the school gives us, instead of trying to use the github cert. Or if that doesn't work then allow the school's cert to authenticate for me

Comment: Note that .crt and .cer extensions are interchangeable, just change the file name extension, they have the same form.

Comment: @Mike they why not put it as an answer?

Comment: So this question is indeed a duplicate since `.crt` and `.cer` means nothing.

Comment: This should not be talking about (and marked with) "certificates", but about CA-certificates instead. Big difference. A normal certificate is good for one specific instance of something. If you install someone's CA certificate though, each and everything that CA will issue in the future will be accepted by your machine.  (Also, different purpose - as the accepted answer explains, this is basically a MITM attack with your cooperation.)

Answer (score 247, accepted):

**TL;DR**

For everything to work and not only your browser, you need to add that CA certificate to the system's trusted CA repository.

In ubuntu:

- Go to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
- Create a new folder, i.e. "sudo mkdir school"
- Copy the .crt file into the school folder
- Make sure the permissions are OK (755 for the folder, 644 for the file)
- Run "sudo update-ca-certificates"

**Why**

Let me explain what is going on also, so the other posters see why they don't need any certificate to use Github over HTTPS.

What is going on there is that your school is intercepting all the SSL communications, probably in order to monitor them.

To do that, what they do is in essence a "man in the middle" attack, and because of that, your browser complains rightfully that it is not being able to verify github's certificate. Your school proxy is taking out github's cert and instead providing its own cert.

When your browser tries to verify the school's provided cert against the CA that signed github's cert, it rightfully fails.

So, for the SSL connection to work in the school, you need to consciously accept that "MITM" attack. And you do that by adding the school's CA certificate as a trusted one.

When you trust that school CA, your verification of the fake github cert will work, since the fake github cert will be verified by the school CA.

Be aware that SSL connection is not safe anymore since your school administrator will be able to intercept all your encrypted connections.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as Mike's without the dpkg-reconfigure that shouldn't be needed. What may be going on is that git or another command line is not being 100% standard regarding their SSL verification. Using what you call "git hack" may be needed in order to workaround the "SSL hack" your school implemented first.

Comment: And also, be aware that you need root permissions to run this commands, so the sudo command needs to be successful, or you will not be able to update the system's Certificate Authorities.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide the additional facts - don't leave the in a comment.

Comment: I believe that should be `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`. See `man update-ca-certificates`, which talks about there being a whitelist for `/usr/share/ca-certificates/` but about how it implicitly trusts everything in the `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` directory.

Comment: on Ubuntu 16.04 after adding the CA to  `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` I had to use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` for it to pickup the CA.

Comment: @Telegrapher Thanks for detail information, this is only applicable in Linux machine, can you also suggest me how to install .crt in macOS.

Comment: For @Gagan and anyone else reading this thread, I searched for this while following this guide that explains how to install on MacOS: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/

Comment: I'm going to add that the cert file must be in the PEM format, otherwise you'll get a confusing error like `skipping certificate.cer ,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL` when doing `sudo update-ca-certificates` and it wouldn't work. You can convert a certificate in a DER (binary) format to PEM with `openssl x509 -inform der -in CERTIFICATE.cer -out CERTIFICATE.crt` (reference: https://www.ssl.com/guide/pem-der-crt-and-cer-x-509-encodings-and-conversions/)

Answer (score 57):

The `ca-certificates` package has the instructions in its `README.Debian`:

> If you want to install local certificate authorities to be implicitly trusted, please put the certificate files as single files ending with `.crt` into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and re-run
>   `update-ca-certificates`.

Note that it mentions a directory different from the other answers here:

```
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
```

After copying into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` you can then update the cert's permissions and run `sudo update-ca-certificates` as mentioned in Telegraphers answer. You will see in the output that the cert was added.

Comment: This worked for me as well on Ubuntu 16.04. The path in the accepted answer did not work for me.

Comment: This has to be a accepted answer this is a working solution for ubuntu server 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 34):

Extensions .crt, .pem and .cer are interchangeable, just change the file name extension, they have the same form. Try this:

```
$ sudo cp mycert.cer /usr/share/ca-certificates/mycert.pem
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
$ git config --global http.sslCAInfo /usr/share/ca-certificates/mycert.pem
```

Comment: Well although this is true, it did not help. But in future it might help people

Comment: I added one more line, try that to make git trust your certificate, note that I changed cer. to .pem in two of the 4 steps instead .crt. @Unicorns Are Very Very Yummy

Comment: If your .CER file is binary (DER format) then you can't just change the extension. Use [`openssl(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/openssl.1ssl.html) to convert the certificate to PEM format. Run: `$ openssl -in mycert.cer -inform DER -out mycert.pem -outform PEM`

Comment: @Archuser  Maybe the right command is this : `openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem`

Comment: Changing the extension from .pem to .crt worked for me but I had to use the .crt extension, like explained in /etc/ca-certificates.conf: "files with extension '.crt' is recognized as available certs".

Answer (score 20):

I read all solutions and solved like this;

```
sudo openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt

sudo mv certificate.crt /usr/share/ca-certificate/

cd /usr/share/ca-certificate

sudo chmod 644 certificate.crt

sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates

sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Comment: Just a note, I have `/usr/share/ca-certificates` on my system but not `/usr/share/ca-certificate/` (note the missing `s`)

Answer (score 14):

I use the following compilation of previous answers:

```
sudo -i
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername site.example.com -connect example.com:443 2>/dev/null | awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/, /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/' >> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca-certificates.crt 
update-ca-certificates
```

Often both `site.example.com` and `example.com` are the same hostnames.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem where installing the certificate in firefox and google chrome worked but Updating in terminal `sudo apt-get update` was not working and giving  403  Forbidden IP errors.
I was too having a sample.cer file. So basically I have to convert it to .crt first.

```
sudo openssl x509 -inform DER -in sample.cer -out sample.crt
```

Still while doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` I couldn't find the required certificate.
The problem with me is that I was copying the certificate at the wrong place.

Instead of copying it at `$/usr/share/ca-certificates`  I was copying it at `$/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`
But by placing it in the right place solved my problem.
But I'm still not able to update the packages or install new packages.

Quick fix (for me on):

Use of ftp instead of http

```
sudo sed -i s/http/ftp/ /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update
```

and above command worked.
Please make a copy of sources.list file before making the changes.

If anything is not clear or not proper please do correct me.

Answer (score 0):

To access a website with `https`, whether you are using a CLI or GUI browser, you don't need your shool certificate.

To use `git` via http(s) you need to register your public key in your profile settings on [GitHub](https://github.com/).

More infos [here](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/). Change your GitHub profile [here](https://github.com/settings/ssh).

---

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install w3m
w3m https://github.com/
```

… works without an additionally certificate.

Comment: This is not correct. He clearly stated his school is intercepting https traffic, and needs the certificate to validate SSL.