# 16.04: How to specify a certificate authority with ldapsearch

Tags: 16.04, openvpn, ldap

I've been trying to debug LDAP connectivity, so I installed `ldapsearch` via `sudo apt install ldap-utils`. Here's the output of the command:

```
# ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldaps://myip -d1 -ZZ
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://myip)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://myip/??base)
ldap_extended_operation_s
ldap_extended_operation
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP myip:636
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying myip:636
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect: 
connect success
TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x42)
TLS: can't connect: (unknown error code).
ldap_err2string
ldap_start_tls: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
    additional info: (unknown error code)
```

Specifically, I'm focusing on this line:
`TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x42)`

I did some googling, and found people explaining to set this setting in a file that exists in a directory named `/etc/openldap`. However, this directory does not exist on the machine--it doesn't seem to have been created during installation of `ldap-utils`.

I can't figure out if there's a way to either tell `ldapsearch` to ignore the trust level of the server's cert, or to pass in some sort of CA. What is the appropriate solution here, to continue with connectivity testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to /etc/ldap/ldap.conf:
`TLS_REQCERT never`

It will prevent ldapsearch from validating the certificate. So not the most secure option. 
You can specify a CA certificate with `TLS_CACERT /path/to/trusted/ca`

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick for my testing purposes. For anyone else messing with a Windows LDAPS AD setup, here's the test command that should return the user information, after making the change mentioned in the above answer:

`ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldaps://YOUR_HOST -w 'LDAP_PASS' -D 'LDAP_BIND' -b "DC=lan" 'sAMAccountName=SOME_USER' -d1` -- 

-d1 will give more verbose debugging information.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it just happened I've found a proper answer: [How to install certificates for command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645818/how-to-install-certificates-for-command-line).

Short story:

- Copy (link) your private CA certificate to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`;
- Run `update-ca-certificates`;
- Verify that `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` contains your certificate (See https://serverfault.com/questions/590870/how-to-view-all-ssl-certificates-in-a-bundle);

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout | grep "your CA"
```

- Repeat your ldapsearch, it should succeed now.

Long story:

On Debian/Ubuntu, LDAP tools are built with GnuTLS. GnuTLS does not work with `/etc/ssl/certs` hash cache. (See note on `TLS_CACERTDIR` in `man ldap.conf`.)

`c_rehash` utility only updates the hash cache, but not `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

To properly update both hash cache and CA bundle, instead of linking your CA cert into `/etc/ssl/certs`, place the link into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and run `update-ca-certificates`.