# Update-ca-certificates: 0 added; 0 removed - how come?

Tags: ssl

I am following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/649463/121383) to install a root certificate for Charles Proxy.

I followed every step exactly as it was outlined, and made sure to set the permissions correctly. However, when I run `sudo update-ca-certificates`, it outputs:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
done.
```

After this, the certificate remains untrusted. I also tried [this](http://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html), which is the same steps but tells me to install it in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` instead. When I do this, `update-ca-certificates` returns an error:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate UbuntuOne-Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
WARNING: Skipping duplicate certificate UbuntuOne-Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
WARNING: charles.pem does not contain a certificate or CRL: skipping
WARNING: dhparam.pem does not contain a certificate or CRL: skipping
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Adding debian:charles.pem
done.
done.
```

And it still does not work. Additionally, installing a SSL cert directly through Charles (`Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Root Certificate`)  does not work, even though it says it installs successfully.

Answer (score 11):

If you're on Debian, try changing from .cer to .crt. File content is still the same.