# I deleted the partition volume where ubuntu 14.04 LTS was installed. now i cant access windows

Tags: 14.04, ppa, boot-repair, add-apt-repository

I am stuck at grub rescue. I tried booting Ubuntu from a live USB, then doing this

```
sudo app-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

the this error came up.

```
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

Comment: Please take a look http://askubuntu.com/questions/429803/cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that-the-ppa-name-or-format-is-correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong command(s) - the correct ones are :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

[Reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Note : When you really deleted the Ubuntu system partition, you better should reinstall Ubuntu.