# Can't add a ppa to install wifi driver in my hp pavillion ac-032tx with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, ubuntu-drivers

[image]

I tried this but it didn't work as you can see. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This PPA works fine from here. Try these Ask Ubuntu questions: 1. http://askubuntu.com/q/429803/57576 2. http://askubuntu.com/q/53146/57576 This should hopefully get you running :)

Comment: You need to be connected to internet for that.

Comment: Are you sure you have a Realtek adapter?

Comment: yup..pretty sure

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi` is running fine on my system.

If it still doesn't work on your system for some reason, you can install the WiFi drivers yourself like this:

1. Clone the drivers repo, [lwfinger/rtlwifi_new](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)
2. Build the drivers by running: `make && sudo make install`
3. Restart the system or just restart the WiFi module by running:

   `sudo modprobe -r <driver-name> && sudo modprobe <driver-name>`

Hope it helps!

Comment: The alternative method is worse, because it requires to re-install the driver after each kernel upgrade. The OP's problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Pilot6 I agree, updating drivers from the ppa is lot easier.