# 'Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support jammy''' when installing "Sublime Text 3" from command line - workaround for PPA?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, ppa, sublime-text

I made the mistake of not searching in the Software Manager which would have made it so easy of course, but it might still help someone perhaps to know the console way.

This is a use case when installing "Sublime Merge Text 3" with a PPA does not work for some unknown reason. After checking the tricks of [Cannot add PPA. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429803/cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that-the-ppa-name-or-format-is-correct), it still threw, as before:

`Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support jammy''.`

when running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3`.

If it seems as if you cannot use PPA here, and you do not want to use the Software Manager (or you just forgot about it like me), how to install the program?

The question is also tagged "sublime-text" but it is just a use case for anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following a guide at [Install Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu & Other Linux [3 Easy Ways]](https://itsfoss.com/sublime-text-3-linux/) which

- adds the GPG key (`Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).`), then
- adds the repository to `sources.list` and then
- installs with apt.

Full copy of the guide:

Open a terminal and use the command below to install the GPG key.
`wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

Out:

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```

After that, create add the repository in your sources.list.
`echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list`

Now refresh the package list and install Sublime Text.
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install sublime-text`

Perhaps it helps someone who cannot use PPA either.

I later found out that it is just in the Software Manager anyway, thus, this console solution would only be needed if you wrote a docker image or other sort of automated installation.